# How does a digital filter $H(z)=1/(1-z^{-1})$ change a continuous rectangular pulse?

Tags: filters, z-transform

I inputted the following signal 
[image]

in this discrete time filter

[image]

and got this output

[image]

Could anyone explain how ? Also how does a discrete filter process a continuous time output ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. You mention a quantizer in the title but then use a filter, and you also have a couple of different transfer functions.

Comment: Your system is an integrator, hence for rectangular pulse the output should be a triangular wave.

Answer (score 1):

Unless otherwise specified, your transfer function (with ROC $|z| > 1$)

$$ H(z) = \frac{1}{1 - z^{-1}}$$ defines an discrete-time **accumulator** with impulse response;
$$h[n] = u[n]$$ and the corresponding output
$$y[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{n} x[k] $$ which reduces to 
$$y[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{n} x[k] $$ for a **causal** input.

So **practically** the accumulator behaves like a continuous-time **integrator** and therefore for an input of **square wave**, you would expect a **triangular wave** output plus some DC term whose value depends on the initial sample timing of the square wave being applied.

Please note that this is for a AC-coupled input square wave, if the input square wave has **nonzero DC** component, then there will also be a **ramp** output term in addition to the triangular wave. However in that case you shoudl clearly indicate the time span of the input, otherwise an indefinitely long input would mean ramp output going to infinity.

Comment: So are you saying that the output i've got is incorrect ?

Comment: if the first plot is the input (discrete-time) sequence and the second plot is the corresponding output sequence, yes you'got incorrect result there.

Comment: btw a discrete-time filter **does not** directly process a continuous-time signal. I'm sure you mean the *quantized samples* of the continuous time input.